# Windows 7 computer crashing while applying updates

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-update

I have a Windows 7 machine that has been running reliably for 2 years and I have been keeping up to date via Microsoft updates. I shut it down for the night and it began doing updates. In the morning it was in a continuous reboot loop.

The machine boots through the BIOS normally. Then the `Starting Windows` screen with logo comes up. After a few seconds the `Applying update operation <nnn> of <mmmm>` text appears very briefly. Then the screen goes black except for the mouse cursor. Then it starts the BIOS boot again.

Each time the `<nnn>` in the message is different, usually between 200 and 300.

I cannot get F8 to bring up the Startup/Repair menu, as is normally possible during boot.

I have booted from my DVD and selected the Repair option at the bottom. None of the options on the repair dialog are useful.

`Startup Repair` says it can't do anything.
There are no Operating Systems listed on the `System Recovery Options` dialog.
There are no `System Images` available.

Because the system does begin booting from the hard drive, into the Applying updates stage, I don't think this is a typical crashed hard drive. I'm wondering if the repair options are all gone simply due to the altered boot process used by updates.

Any ideas for how to get out of this without a fresh install?

UPDATE: I used MiniTool's Partiton Wizard and was able to confirm that all of my files were still there, but there was no `Windows` folder. So I don't think any form of recovery will work. Backing up the data file, clean install, restore.

Comment: Are you saying the system at least progresses through the updates? Because if it is progressing (higher current update operation count and/or different number of operations remaining each time) then maybe there's just something about the set of updates you installed that needs lots of reboots?

Comment: Seems that "reboot on error" is enabled. It will be interesting to boot into safe mode soyou can disable this and see the BSOD details that surely happens after reboot. The F8 options non working are very strange

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - no, the update number is randomly higher and lower. It seems to start from the beginning each time and stop at a different point.

Comment: @ÁxelCostasPena - yes, I tried many times to get F8 to work.

Comment: Question should be closed now since OP isn't interested anymore in the answer to the original question, am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct - I'm past that particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to boot into recovery mode from the installation DVD, you can type

```
dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
```

on the recovery command prompt. This will rollback pending updates.

Comment: Useful to know. I have discovered that though all my data files are there, there is no Windows folder - so I am now doing a clean install and then restore data.

Comment: Sad to hear that. Surely you initially suffered a BSOD during the first attempt to install those updates, while Windows were writing itself to the system folder, so the file index corrupted, then you achieved current situation.